# I want to open a contact form after button click (Android)

Tags: android

I am designing a form with a button. When I click on that button, I want to open up a new registration form.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

This tutorial shows you exactly what to do - http://www.itcsolutions.eu/2011/08/31/android-tutorial-how-to-create-and-display-a-new-form-window-or-activity/

If you want this result:

[image]